# Prepared statement, loop results to get more results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a query where I'm taking several results from a single table. I then need to loop through each result to get information from other tables, however, I can't get it to work.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

    $type = 1;

    if ($stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE type = ?')) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $type);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($username);

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            if ($stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT count FROM posts WHERE username = ?')) {
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->bind_result($result2);
                $stmt->close();
            }
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }

?>
```

I get an error:

```
Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Use a different name for the inner variable, eg $stmt2

Comment: indeed, don't overwrite your loop-variable inside the loop. This breaks the while-loop :)

Comment: I'm getting the error `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now` now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend a native SQL `JOIN` for this because it will avoid unnecessary overhead in sending potentially thousands of queries:

```
SELECT
    u.username,
    p.count
FROM
    users u
        LEFT JOIN // processed as LEFT OUTER JOIN so the syntax is interchangeable just fyi
        posts p
        ON u.username = p.username
WHERE
    p.type = ?
```

**Explaining LEFT JOIN only, we'll keep it simple =)**

- In the SQL above we start with username from the users table as a whole
- `users u` just grants us the shortcut syntax for `u.username` so that SQL is readable and doesn't fubar
- Next we want to attach the `posts p` table where `u.username = p.username` because we need the `p.count` for each username
- Lastly we filter this conglomerate of data based on `p.type` being equal to something

---

Please note that are many things at play here depending on the DBMS. Such things include query optimizers, the exact point of filtering, etc... but that is far outside the scope of simply getting the hang of what we are trying to achieve conceptually so I will not go into detail because it will only cause confusion.

Comment: I never understood JOIN queries, even though I've read a lot on them. Is there a tutorial that particularly helped you?

Comment: No tutorials in particular. I've been fortunate enough to get dunked head-first into existing systems that use them all over the place so it was sink or swim for me. I can try and add a conceptual explanation in my answer if you would like.

Comment: I'm not at my main computer right now, but as soon as I am, I'll give this a go. The explanation was great, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are overwritting your stmt variable. You should use another one, like

```
$type = 1;

if ($stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE type = ?')) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $type);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($username);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        if ($stmtCnt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT count FROM posts WHERE username = ?')) {
            $stmtCnt->bind_param('s', $username);
            $stmtCnt->execute();
            $stmtCnt->bind_result($result2);
            $stmtCnt->close();
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now` now.